# Cakephp - Model Transactions for insert / update / delete

Tags: cakephp, model, transactions, innodb, commit

I have a table that has several fields, 2 of these fields are "startdate" and "enddate", which mark the validity of the record. If i insert 1 new record, the new record cannot overlap with other records in terms of start date and end date.

Hence on insertion of new record i may need to adjust the value of "startdate" and "enddate" of pre-existing records so they don't overlap with the new record. Similarly, any preexisting records that have 100% overlap with the new record, will need to be deleted.

My table is an InnoDB table, which i know supports such transactions.

Are there any examples which show use of insert / update / delete using transactions (all must succeed in order for any one of them to succeed and be commited) ?
I don't know how to do this. Most examples only show the use of saveAssociated() which i'm not sure is capable of catering for delete operations?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the [beforeSave callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) to search for the preexisting records and delete them before saving your new record.

from the docs:

> Place any pre-save logic in this function. This function executes immediately after model data has been successfully validated, but just before the data is saved. This function should also return true if you want the save operation to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to do Transactions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html

That should allow you to run your queries - you start a transaction, perform any required actions, and then commit or rollback based on the outcome.  Although, given your description I'd think doing some reads and adjusting your data before committing anything might be a better approach. Either way, transactions aren't a bad idea though!